# How to use RTSP over HTTP?

Tags: c, networking, communication, ip-camera

Can someone please explain what is meant by RTSP using HTTP. How can I get video stream on TCP instead of UDP??

Comment: See [Tunnelling RTSP and RTP through HTTP](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/icefloe/dispatch028.html) Its pretty detailed.